# how to use CURL and PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser with object

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Using CURL to get content from website. Getting response in object. How to convert that object in to PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

```
function get_data($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0");
    //curl_exec($ch);
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(curl_exec($ch));
    print_r( $dom );
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$data = get_data($url);

?>
```

**Result**

```
simple_html_dom Object ( [root] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 3 [tag] => text [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => simple_html_dom_node Object *RECURSION* [_] => Array ( [4] => 1 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 2 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 3 [tag] => text [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => simple_html_dom_node Object *RECURSION* [_] => Array ( [4] => 1 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 2 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) [1] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 3 [tag] => text [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object *RECURSION* ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 2 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) [_] => Array ( [4] => 1 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) ) [callback] => [lowercase] => 1 [original_size] => 1 [size] => 1 [pos:protected] => 1 [char:protected] => [cursor:protected] => 2 [parent:protected] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 3 [tag] => text [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => simple_html_dom_node Object *RECURSION* [_] => Array ( [4] => 1 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 2 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) [token_blank:protected] => [token_equal:protected] => =/> [token_slash:protected] => /> [token_attr:protected] => > [_charset] => UTF-8 [_target_charset] => UTF-8 [default_br_text:protected] => [default_span_text] => [self_closing_tags:protected] => Array ( [img] => 1 [br] => 1 [input] => 1 [meta] => 1 [link] => 1 [hr] => 1 [base] => 1 [embed] => 1 [spacer] => 1 ) [block_tags:protected] => Array ( [root] => 1 [body] => 1 [form] => 1 [div] => 1 [span] => 1 [table] => 1 ) [optional_closing_tags:protected] => Array ( [tr] => Array ( [tr] => 1 [td] => 1 [th] => 1 ) [th] => Array ( [th] => 1 ) [td] => Array ( [td] => 1 ) [li] => Array ( [li] => 1 ) [dt] => Array ( [dt] => 1 [dd] => 1 ) [dd] => Array ( [dd] => 1 [dt] => 1 ) [dl] => Array ( [dd] => 1 [dt] => 1 ) [p] => Array ( [p] => 1 ) [nobr] => Array ( [nobr] => 1 ) [b] => Array ( [b] => 1 ) [option] => Array ( [option] => 1 ) ) [doc:protected] => 1 [noise:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not creating the DOM correctly, you must do it like this:

```
// Create a DOM object
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$dom->load(curl_exec($ch))

print_r( $dom );
```

Check the [Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more details...

**Edit**

It seems that is a cURL settings problem, please refer to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) to configure it correctly...

This is a function I usualy use to download some pages, feel free to adjust it to your needs:

```
function dlPage($href) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4");
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Create a DOM object
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $dom->load($str);

    return $dom;
    }

$url = 'http://www.example.com/';
$data = dlPage($url);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Getting same object like above on result

Comment: i also did **print_r(curl_exec($ch));**. its returning 1;

Comment: thank you for update. Still getting an object. **print_r(curl_exec($curl));** showing error.. http://s23.postimg.org/p3xw754t7/main.jpg

Comment: @AlizainPrasla, Well, it is working for me... `echo gettype(curl_exec($curl));` will give the value `string` meaning that curl_exec() is returning a string wich is the html code, then when you print it displays the scraped page, and that's [what I'm getting](http://s27.postimg.org/adh9alo3n/dom.png)... So, are you sure the error comes from here ? try executing that code from a separate file and check the result...

Comment: Well descriptive answer. If i change my url to www.example.com so its works exactly what you explained. but if i change my url to vconnect.com/nigeria/businesses-from-a its showing error which i shown you above

Comment: @AlizainPrasla, Some sites don't like the default UserAgent, so simply change it (as it was in your example) [Answer updated]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45493/discussion-between-alizain-prasla-and-enissay)

Comment: Thank you @Enissay. is there any alternative?

Comment: I can't navigato to nodes, getElementsByTagName (non object) but other query independent from curl ( new DOMDocument(); ...loadHTML($url);...), works correctly

Comment: @delive make sure you're downloading the page correctly (print the html source code) then adapt your code to match it accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

Curl will return a string containing the HTML right? Just use the [quick start sample](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

```
$html = str_get_html(curl_exec($ch));
```

Comment: Curl is not returning string.. its a OBJECT. check result

Comment: `curl_exec` will return a string if you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`. If you set it to `false`, it will output the result directly. In that case, you're getting a boolean telling you if the exec was succesfull.