# Simple html dom div downloading issue

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Here's some php code that i wrote. It's mainly based on docs.
It's obviously using simple html dom
The problem is it doesnt really work and i dunno why.

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params($context, array('user_agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"));
$html = file_get_html('http://www.ask.fm', 0, $context);
$elem = $html->find('div[id=heads]', 0);
var_dump($elem);
?>
```

What i want is to set useragent which i tried to do above that sentence. And then i want to download div with id "heads". That's not much but i couldnt figure it out in any way.

Comment: Use curl instead like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186309/1519058

Comment: what do you mean by download div? you already got the element? whats the final output?

Comment: the problem is that this code shouldnt work but it doesnt. by downloading div i mean to fetch div from other site and echo it out

Comment: it works fine in my end, `echo $elem;` and it already shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include "simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php";
function curl($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // you may set this options if you need to follow redirects. Though I didn't get any in your case
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);  
    return $content;
}       

$html = str_get_html(curl("http://www.ask.fm"));
echo $elem = $html->find('div[id=heads]', 0);
?>
```

I think it is useful for you