# Trying to get property of non object Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get content of `<div class="clearfix" id="searchResultsDiv">` from the link in my code. Whatever I try it shows a Notice as follow

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\homeshop\index.php on line 20**

```
$link="http://www.homeshop18.com/samsung/categoryid:3027/search:samsung/inStock:true/sort:Popularity/?it_category=MN&it_action=MA-MMAA01&it_label=MN-MMAA01-140906000003-PD-MA-OT-OT-SR_Samsung-0_0-0-MNU101-MA-140730-OT-OT-SR&it_value=0";
$productPage=file_get_html($link);
$wholeContent=$productPage->find('div[id=searchResultsDiv]');
echo $wholeContent->plaintext; //line 20
```

There is an element with this id but still i cant do it. Where I am wrong?

Comment: Try $wholeContent=$productPage->find('div[id="searchResultsDiv"]'); - No idea if that would fix it, but go ahead and try it out :)

Comment: @JacobJohansson isn't like syntax? however i tried and no positive result.

Comment: Your function `file_get_html()` is not returning an object, you need to start there. Posting that function in your question may help.

Comment: Just gave it a thought, I always write like that in CSS.

Comment: that means `$wholeContent` isn't an object, which probably means that `->find()` didn't find anything.

Comment: It does return an object, but `find` is not returning an object... it is supposed to, though...

Comment: @vascowhite That function is part of the Simple HTML DOM library, not his own function.

Comment: @rm-vanda oh, yes, you are right. A `var_dump($productPage->find('div[id=searchResultsDiv]');` Is probably good place to start then.

Comment: Try using cURL to download the page before loading the dom... [`HERE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186309/1519058)'s an example...

Comment: It works for me. It doesn't print anything because there's no text in that DIV, but I don't get an error.

Comment: @Barmar check the nested divs it has text. plaintext will print all the text.

Comment: @Enissay tried this earlier but nothing works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`find` returns an array of matching elements, even if there's just one match. You need to index it to get the element.

```
if ($wholeContent) {
    echo $wholeContent[0]->plaintext;
}
```

Comment: if $wholeContent->plaintext doesnt work then how come it works?

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't get an error from it. But when I change to this, I get the desired text.

Comment: Even i am getting now but what is happening??

Comment: Sorry, I can't parse that question.

Comment: but now i am unable to get the inner elements of $wholeContent[0] using find()

Comment: `$wholeContents[0]->find('div.box')` works for me. Remember, this is also an array, you'll have to iterate over it.

Comment: BTW, `find()` returns null if nothing is found... So, an `if($wholeContent){ ... }` should work too...

Answer (score 2):

To extend @Barmar answere, you could also do as :

```
$wholeContent=$productPage->find('div[id=searchResultsDiv]', 0);
$wholeContent->plaintext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no duplicate `#searchResultsDiv` in your code.

In that case `find()` would return the **array of object** rather than **object** itself

Comment: It's not his code, it's the Samsung web site. If you check the source, you'll see that there's no duplicate.