# How To Use html dom parser to get images out of an array of links

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

i was working with html dom parser(got it from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract images from websites . so i put every websites i want to extract images from in an array but then if i put it inside a for loop the code is not working .
sorry for my bad english

```
<?php
require("html/simple_html_dom.php");
$aray = array("www.google.com","www.yahoo.com");
for($xx=0;$xx<count($aray);$xx++)
{
 $html=file_get_html($aray[$xx];
  foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Use cURL instead to download the pages, then parse them with simple_html_dom... Here's some examples on how to proceed: [`Example 1`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18668562/1519058) [`Example 2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186309/1519058)

Comment: And don't mix for and foreach loops, you'll confuse yourself. Stick to foreach.