# build PHP url parser scraper

Tags: javascript, php, forms, parsing

i want to know what and how these websites get all the info from just pasting the link inside a form

i want to build something similiar

a user paste a URL inside the form and a script runs to get all the information

https://www.lynks.com/en/eg/pricing

https://www.edfa3ly.co/cart

i know the question is very vague but i can't find any info how to get the info from amazon or other websites, i know that i can use amazon aff API somehow, but for everything else how can i do that?

Comment: You could process download the page via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start by downloading the page in PHP with curl.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then use regular expressions, an HTML parser or the like to find the data you're looking for.

Looks like this question was also already answered here: [how to use CURL and PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser with object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185539/how-to-use-curl-and-php-simple-html-dom-parser-with-object)